# How to find Bundle Identifier from known PID?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, pid

I have the pid (process identifier) of an arbitrary running process. How can I find the bundle identifier (if any) of the associated application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a way that works in 10.2 and later: First call `GetProcessForPID` to turn the pid into a `ProcessSerialNumber`.  Then call `ProcessInformationCopyDictionary` to get the bundle ID.  (Added:  these functions are deprecated in OS 10.9.  I don't know if they still exist in the 10.10 SDK.)

Answer (score 7):

I've found an answer which works on 10.6 only:

`[[NSRunningApplication runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier:pid] bundleIdentifier]`