# How to obtain an application's Bundle ID (or plist path) from only the PID?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, plist, nsuserdefaults

Similar to ["How to find Bundle Identifier from known PID?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309681/how-to-find-bundle-identifier-from-known-pid) and to ["How to read plist information (bundle id) from a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328501/how-to-read-plist-information-bundle-id-from-a-shell-script), but different.. as those are both related to Xcode build variable expansion, etc.

**My question is how, in a BASH shell, where they only known value is the process' PID, how can one obtain that process'  *PATH, or unique "Bundle ID".***

I am sure there is a hideous regex to parse ps, but I'm hoping for something cleaner and more portable.  The comments in those prior mentioned posts included

```
BUNDLE_ID=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :CFBundleIdentifier" "${BUILD_ROOT}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}")
```

However, I do not think `plistbuddy` is installed on every Mac, and more importantly, my question is within a theoretical script, NOT within an Xcode build phase..

I've tried `plutil`, `plistkit`, and `plistdump`, and none of them seem to do the trick..

The reason I am trying to achieve this is to be able to execute `defaults read` / `write` functions without hardcoding the BundleID of the parent process.  I know how to pass this info as an argument to a script.. but I want to be able to doubt check.. within the script.

Comment: i accept them when they're answered.  also, I've answered 70 questions vs. asking 16. and most of them already had accepted answers. i post when i can add to the solution.. and i accept an answer when it solves the problem, not just because someone posted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a hideous regex to parse the output of `ps` – the `ps` utility already does what you ask of it. Calling it with the (admittedly somewhat arcane looking) following options

```bsh
ps [-ww] -o comm= -p <pid>
```

will return the path to the executable belonging to your PID (the `-ww` argument is only needed if you output to a terminal, as `ps` will truncate the returned path without it. It should not be necessary otherwise).

The problem with retrieving a bundle ID from there is that not all processes map to bundles with an Info.plist (which defines the bundle ID) – notably, *nix type executables are not bundles and thus have no bundle ID. Also, even in the case of app bundles, `ps` returns the core executable of an application, not the path to the bundle itself. As the path to the executable inside an application bundle is standardized, however (it resides in `Path.app/Contents/MacOS`), you can retrieve it with a bit of directory traversal.

Assuming you have stored the output of the `ps` call above in the variable `execfile`, this

```bsh
[[ ${execfile%/*} =~ ^.+/Contents/MacOS$ ]] && defaults read "${execfile%/*/*}"/Info CFBundleIdentifier
```

will retrieve bundle identifiers for likely paths by using `defaults` to retrieve the value of the `CFBundleIdentifier` key of the `Info.plist` file every application bundle contains at its root.

Comment: Anything that remains arcane in 2012 is usually also known as "discouraged".  I don't think "they" want "us" to do this. Looks good though... will test and report back.

Comment: @alexgray: I tend to agree on the first part (two decades of evolution of the \*nix toolchain do not stop me from muttering passages straight out of the *Unix Haters Handbook* whenever I delve into the shell… I mean: `-ww`? really?). Did work on my system, for what it is worth.

Comment: Ha!  I had never heard of [The Unix Hater's Handbook](http://m.simson.net/ugh.pdf).  Hillarious.

Comment: Fact I own a first hand, then new paperback copy serves as a good reminder I’ve been around computers far too long. So has the \*nix toolchain. Closing this off before some mod nukes the whole comment thread for being OT. Which it totally is.

Comment: Works like a charm…  `execfile=\`ps -ww -o comm= -p 48022\` && [[ ${execfile%/*} =~ ^.+/Contents/MacOS$ ]] && defaults read "${execfile%/*/*}"/Info CFBundleIdentifier` ->
com.mrgray.whatever.  Now I just have to remember why I wanted to do this, lol. PS: Hope your copy came with the [UNIX barf bag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_UNIX-HATERS_Handbook)!

Comment: @alexgray: well, “they” recommend “we” use `$()` instead of back ticks. Otherwise, glad it works for you.

Comment: Just a note about why this works: `defaults read` is pulling a value from the application bundle's Info.plist file. Expanding the final part of @kopischke's command expanded looks like this: `defaults read /Applications/Mail.app/Contents/Info CFBundleIdentifier` which returns `com.apple.mail`

Comment: @joemaller thanks for clarifying – as OP knew the internals, my solution was admittedly light on basic explanation. Amended.